# Constructor of parent class can not be applied to given types in child constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I extended penthouse from flat class. I know that when I create object from extended class, the parent's constructor is called first.

But I don't get it why I can't change the Penthouse constructor to initialize new fields that only exist in Penthouse. How should I change my Penthouse constructor so it does not conflict with Flat constructor?

> error: constructor Flat in class Flat cannot be applied to given types;
>       Penthouse(int new_jakuzi, boolean has_elev){

```
class Penthouse extends Flat{

    int number_jakuzi ;
    boolean has_elevator;

    Penthouse(int new_jakuzi, boolean has_elev){
        cena = 0 ;
        address = "unknown";
        number_jakuzi = new_jakuzi;
        has_elevator = has_elev ;
    }

    Penthouse(String novi_addrees, int novi_cena){

    }

    void advertise(){
        System.out.println("great penthouse on sale!" + 
        " number of jakuzi " + number_jakuzi + 
        " it has elevator: " + has_elevator+
        " at price: " + cena) ;
    }
}

class Flat{
    int cena ;
    String address;
    Flat(String novi_address, int new_cena){
        cena = new_cena ;
        address = novi_address ;
    }

    void show_data(){
        System.out.println("cena: " + cena  + " address: " + address);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        Flat x = new Flat("bogenbai", 45);
        x.show_data();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `Flat` has no constructor that takes an int and a boolean, you must either create one or invoke whichever `Flat` constructor you want explicitly from the `Penthouse` constructor :

```
Penthouse(int new_jakuzi, boolean has_elev){ 
    super ("something", 15); // for example;
    cena = 0 ;
    address = "unknown";
    number_jakuzi = new_jakuzi;
    has_elevator = has_elev ;
}
```

P.S. please use Java naming conventions for your identifiers (for example `hasElevator` instead of `has_elevator`). Your code is painful to read.

Answer (score 1):

Flat class doesn't have a default(no args) constructor. Therefore in the extended class constructors you must explicitly call an appropriate super class(Flat) constructor. This should be the first call in your extended class constructor. If Flat did have a default constructor, compiler would have done this for you using the default.

Comment: yes, i figured out that i had to ALWAYS include super( new_cena, new_address) constructor in EVERY of my Penthouse constructors!

Answer (score 1):

Adding default constructor to Flat class will resolve the error:

```
Class Flat {
     Flat() {

     }
}
```